# Updated to Rails 4.2.2 and got: User email_changed? method not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've just updated to **rails 4.2.2** and can't create a **user** anymore. (it was working before).

I have the **user's email** delegated to another model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable

  ...
  belongs_to :contact, :inverse_of => :user
  delegate :name, :email, :to => :contact, :allow_nil => true

  # Validations
  ...

end
```

Now, when I try to create a User, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `email_changed?' for #<User:0xddb3be0>
from /home/.../gems/activemodel-4.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
```

If I add this to **user.rb**, it works again:

```
def email_changed?
  false
end
```

Is there any problem with this solution? Is there a better alternative?

Obs:

In a more complete log, I got the following lines:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `email_changed?' for #<User:0xf75da14>
     # /home/.../gems/activemodel-4.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
     # /home/.../gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Recoverable>'
     # /home/.../gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/.../gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
     # /home/.../gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `call'
     # /home.../gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
     # /home/.../gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
     # /home/.../gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
     # /home/.../gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
     # /home/.../gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
     # /home/.../gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
     # /home/.../gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_save_callbacks'
     # /home/.../gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
     # /home/.../gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:142:in `save!'
     ...
```

Is there something to do with the Devise's **:recoverable** module? (using devise-3.5.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look into **devise gem**, recoverable module, and found [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L33):

```
included do
  before_update :clear_reset_password_token, if: :encrypted_password_changed?
  before_save do
    if email_changed? || encrypted_password_changed?
      clear_reset_password_token
    end
  end
end
```

It was included by [this commit](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/e641b4b7b97159054b7d92fb14df557ac18ae6f4). It clears the **reset_password_token** if the user's email changed which is correct.

In my particular case, the **User** doesn't have the option of changing his email and the email was delegated to another model. He can only change his password.

Since this is an odd use case, it doesn't seem to be that bad adding to User.rb this:

```
def email_changed?
  false
end
```

There is a problem with this solution if some other important email verification is added by devise using the method `email_changed?` That might cause problems in the future as the method is "stubbed".